# Stored procedure does not run inside a for loop of 100 000 rows

Tags: oracle, for-loop, stored-procedures

I have a table with 100000 records, and I have to make calculations with each row, I make the calculations with the following SP

```
    PROCEDURE PROCESS_DATA(TOTAL_PREG_IN IN NUMBER, SIN_RESPUESTA_IN IN NUMBER, CORRECTAS_IN IN NUMBER, ERRONEAS_IN IN NUMBER, TIEMPO_IN IN VARCHAR2, NOTAS_DATOS_ID_IN IN NUMBER, ESQUEMA_IN IN NUMBER, FilasAfectadas OUT NUMBER)
    IS
    CALIFICACION NUMBER;
    REGLA NUMBER;
    LEVEL_ID NUMBER;
    TIEMPO_AUX VARCHAR2(5);
    TIEMPO NUMBER;
    e_div_zero EXCEPTION;

    BEGIN
        IF (CORRECTAS_IN IS NOT NULL AND ERRONEAS_IN IS NOT NULL) THEN

            IF (SIN_RESPUESTA_IN = 0 AND (CORRECTAS_IN + ERRONEAS_IN) = TOTAL_PREG_IN) THEN
                REGLA:=1;
                IF(TOTAL_PREG_IN = 0) THEN
                    RAISE e_div_zero;
                END IF;
                CALIFICACION := (CORRECTAS_IN * ESQUEMA_IN)/ TOTAL_PREG_IN;
            ELSE IF ((SIN_RESPUESTA_IN >= 1 AND SIN_RESPUESTA_IN <= 4) AND (CORRECTAS_IN + ERRONEAS_IN + SIN_RESPUESTA_IN) = TOTAL_PREG_IN) THEN
                REGLA := 2;
                IF(TOTAL_PREG_IN = 0) THEN
                    RAISE e_div_zero;
                END IF;
                CALIFICACION := (CORRECTAS_IN * ESQUEMA_IN)/ TOTAL_PREG_IN;
            ELSE IF ((SIN_RESPUESTA_IN = 5 OR SIN_RESPUESTA_IN = 10) AND (CORRECTAS_IN + ERRONEAS_IN + SIN_RESPUESTA_IN) = TOTAL_PREG_IN) THEN
                REGLA := 3;
                IF(CORRECTAS_IN + ERRONEAS_IN = 0) THEN
                    RAISE e_div_zero;
                END IF;
                CALIFICACION := (CORRECTAS_IN * ESQUEMA_IN)/(CORRECTAS_IN + ERRONEAS_IN);
            ELSE IF ((SIN_RESPUESTA_IN >= 6 AND SIN_RESPUESTA_IN <= 9) AND (CORRECTAS_IN + ERRONEAS_IN) = TOTAL_PREG_IN) THEN
                REGLA := 4;
                IF(TOTAL_PREG_IN = 0) THEN
                    RAISE e_div_zero;
                END IF;
                CALIFICACION := (CORRECTAS_IN * ESQUEMA_IN)/ TOTAL_PREG_IN;
            ELSE IF (CORRECTAS_IN + ERRONEAS_IN + SIN_RESPUESTA_IN != TOTAL_PREG_IN) THEN
                REGLA := 5;
                IF(CORRECTAS_IN + ERRONEAS_IN + SIN_RESPUESTA_IN = 0 ) THEN
                    RAISE e_div_zero;
                END IF;
                CALIFICACION := (CORRECTAS_IN * ESQUEMA_IN) / (CORRECTAS_IN + ERRONEAS_IN + SIN_RESPUESTA_IN );
            ELSE IF (SIN_RESPUESTA_IN > 10) THEN
                REGLA := 6;
                IF((CORRECTAS_IN + ERRONEAS_IN) > (TOTAL_PREG_IN/2))THEN
                    IF(CORRECTAS_IN + ERRONEAS_IN = 0 ) THEN
                        RAISE e_div_zero;
                    END IF;
                    CALIFICACION := (CORRECTAS_IN * ESQUEMA_IN) / (CORRECTAS_IN + ERRONEAS_IN);
                ELSE
                    CALIFICACION := ESQUEMA_IN * 0.8;
                END IF;
            ELSE IF (CORRECTAS_IN = 0 AND ERRONEAS_IN = 0) THEN
                REGLA := 7;
                SELECT LEVEL AS id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TIEMPO_IN, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL) AS data
                INTO LEVEL_ID, TIEMPO_AUX
                FROM dual where level = 2
                CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(TIEMPO_IN, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;

                TIEMPO := TO_NUMBER(TIEMPO_AUX);

                IF(TIEMPO >= 9) THEN
                    CALIFICACION := ESQUEMA_IN * 0.8;
                END IF;

            END IF;
            END IF;
            END IF;
            END IF;
            END IF;
            END IF;
            END IF;
        ELSE 
            REGLA:=7;
            SELECT LEVEL AS id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TIEMPO_IN, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL) AS data
                INTO LEVEL_ID, TIEMPO_AUX
                FROM dual where level = 2
                CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(TIEMPO_IN, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;

                TIEMPO := TO_NUMBER(TIEMPO_AUX);

                IF(TIEMPO >= 9) THEN
                    CALIFICACION := ESQUEMA_IN * 0.8;
                END IF;
        END IF;

        EXCEPTION 
        WHEN e_div_zero THEN
            calificacion := -1;

        INSERT INTO TABLA_AC AC (AC.AC_REGLA, AC.AC_FECHA_CALIFICACION, AC.AC_CALIFICACION, AC.AC_ARCHIVONOTAS_ID)
        VALUES (REGLA, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), CALIFICACION, NOTAS_DATOS_ID_IN );

        FilasAfectadas:= SQL%RowCount;
        COMMIT;
    END PROCESS_DATA;
```

And I call this sp inside another sp in a for loop

```
PROCEDURE MASIVE_PROCESS(FilasAfectadas_OUT OUT NUMBER)
IS
datos_notas t_row_datos_nota;
contador number := 0;
contador2 number := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT nd.* bulk collect INTO datos_notas 
    FROM SGC_ARCHIVO_NOTAS_DATOS nd
    inner join SGC_ARCHIVO_NOTAS an ON an.AN_ID = nd.AND_ID_ARCHIVO;

    FOR idx IN datos_notas.FIRST..datos_notas.LAST
    Loop
        DB_ESCHEMA.PKG_TEST.PROCESS_DATA(
        TOTAL_PREG_IN        => datos_notas(idx).AND_TOTAL_PREG,
        SIN_RESPUESTA_IN     => datos_notas(idx).AND_SIN_RESPUESTA,
        CORRECTAS_IN         => datos_notas(idx).AND_CORRECTAS,
        ERRONEAS_IN          => datos_notas(idx).AND_ERRONEAS,
        TIEMPO_IN            => datos_notas(idx).AND_TIEMPO,
        NOTAS_DATOS_ID_IN        => datos_notas(idx).AND_ID,
        ESQUEMA_IN           => datos_notas(idx).AND_ESQUEMA_CALF,
        FILASAFECTADAS   => contador);
        contador2 := contador2 +1;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('cont ' || contador2 );
    END LOOP;
    FilasAfectadas_OUT := contador;

END MASIVE_PROCESS;
```

The variable counter2 reaches 100000 records, but only 256 or 512 records of the sp that are executed in the for loop are inserted.

**What is the problem with this code?**

Comment: good opportunity to use the debugger, you can walk your if then's in the loop and see what's happening for each insert

Comment: Your code does seem to calculate a value for "calificacion" but doesn't seem to do anything with the result. Only in case of a e_div_zero you do an insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the indentation in your code, it looks like your intention is that if there is a division by zero error, `calificacion` is set to 1 and then the exception handling is done.  That is not, however, what you've written.  Everything between `EXCEPTION` and `END process_data` is part of your exception handler.  So you only insert into `tabla_ac` if there was a division by zero error.

```
        EXCEPTION 
        WHEN e_div_zero THEN
            calificacion := -1;

        INSERT INTO TABLA_AC AC (AC.AC_REGLA, AC.AC_FECHA_CALIFICACION, AC.AC_CALIFICACION, AC.AC_ARCHIVONOTAS_ID)
        VALUES (REGLA, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), CALIFICACION, NOTAS_DATOS_ID_IN );

        FilasAfectadas:= SQL%RowCount;
        COMMIT;
    END PROCESS_DATA;
```

I expect that you intended something like this with an extra nested PL/SQL block

```
BEGIN
  BEGIN -- BEGIN the new nested PL/SQL block
    IF (CORRECTAS_IN IS NOT NULL AND ERRONEAS_IN IS NOT NULL) THEN
      <<rest of your code>>
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN e_div_zero THEN
      calificacion := -1;
  END; -- END the nested PL/SQL block

  INSERT INTO TABLA_AC AC (AC.AC_REGLA, AC.AC_FECHA_CALIFICACION, AC.AC_CALIFICACION, AC.AC_ARCHIVONOTAS_ID)
    VALUES (REGLA, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), CALIFICACION, NOTAS_DATOS_ID_IN );

  FilasAfectadas:= SQL%RowCount;
  COMMIT;
END PROCESS_DATA;
```

A couple of other comments not related to your immediate problem..

1) If you want to have an `IF` statement with multiple `ELSE` conditions, use `ELSIF` rather than starting new `IF` statements.  That way you don't end up with half a dozen `END IF` statements in a row.  It makes much more sense to say

```
IF <<condition 1>> THEN
  <<do something>>
ELSIF <<condition 2>> THEN
  <<do something else>>
ELSIF <<condition 3>> THEN
  <<do a third thing>>
ELSE
  <<do a final thing>>
END IF;
```

2) If you have a `COMMIT` in your procedure, the vast majority of the runtime will be the result of trying to run 100,000 commits.  That's going to take hundreds of times more time than inserting 100,000 rows and doing a single commit in the outer procedure.

It does not appear that your code is designed to be re-entrant so it is probably functionally problematic to have interim commits as well.  What happens if you've processed 50,000 rows and your code throws an exception?  You'd have no apparent way to restart the process at row 50,001 so if you re-ran your loop, you'd end up with 150,000 rows in `tabla_ac` rather than 100,000 which is unlikely to be what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was helpful!,  I will refactor code with a savepoint to make a rollback in case of exception. 
**Can I have another block of exceptions in the same sp?**

Comment: @JuanPinzón - I'm not sure what "another block of exceptions" means to you-- you can have additional nested PL/SQL blocks or you can catch additional exceptions in your exception handler.  I'm not quite sure if either of those are what you're asking.  Adding a savepoint would not seem likely to address either the performance or the functional issue with interim commits and, unless you do it well, will tend to negatively impact the supportability of your code by causing it to hide exceptions.

Comment: I want catch additional exceptions, for example: when a value is null and a column does not allow null values at the time of insertion, in this case, **would I need a new block of exceptions?**

Comment: @JuanPinzón - You can have as many `WHEN <<exception>>` clauses as you would like in your exception handler.

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave, your answers have been great